# get values which only occur once in a vector

Tags: regular-expression, python, perl

There is a vector of numbers I have which are in ascending order (it is called t8_)

```
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 91 92 94
```

The problem is that some numbers happen two times. I don't want to remove them, but they have to become two numbers which are distinct and *not* floating point. I thought first about iterating through the vector:

```
which(duplicated(t8)) - that would be 9 and then go on 

t8[which(duplicated(t8))]<-t8[which(duplicated(t8))]+1
```

The next vector would be

```
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 92 92 94
```

Repeating same process:

```
which(duplicated(t8)) - that would be 10 and the go on 

t8[which(duplicated(t8))]<-t8[which(duplicated(t8))]+1
```

when the vector would be

```
 2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 92 993 94
```

I tried `sort -u` and `sort -nu` (they do not work).

Is there  a perl or python way to do that interactively...till no duplicate numbers are present?

I would like to do this with a file to put to the function...edit...

The answer is not working with my vector file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp67eiw4ns9rr07/num?dl=0

Comment: could yu please tell me why this is unclear..befor edownvo

Answer (score 1):

The following script reads a vector of integers from each line of stdin.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a vec; do
        # INT_MIN for bash: 32-bit bash also supports 64-bit integers.
        min=$((-1<<63)) 
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#vec[@]}; i++)); do
                (( min = vec[i] = vec[i] > min ? vec[i] : min + 1 ))
        done
        echo "${vec[@]}"
done
```

Sample input:

```
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 91 92 94
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
91 91 91
-1000 -900 -100 -100 -100 0 0 0
5 4 3 2 1 0
 1      1  1 1 1
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./script.sh < input.txt 
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 92 93 94
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
91 92 93
-1000 -900 -100 -99 -98 0 1 2
5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5
```

Let me know if the output isn't as you expected or wanted.

---

**Updated:**
This version would process all integers over all lines from stdin
as one input, not line by line.
It would be capable of accepting lines of arbitrary length.

```
#!/bin/sh

min=$((-1<<63))

tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' |
while read val; do
        case ${val#[-+]} in
                ''|*[!0-9]*) continue ;;
        esac
        min=$((val > min ? val : min + 1))
        echo $min
done |
paste -s -d' ' -
```

Sample session:

```
$ echo -e '2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 91 92 94' | ./script.sh
2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 92 93 94
$ echo -e '91 91 91' | ./script.sh
91 92 93
$ echo -e '5 4 3 2 1 0' | ./script.sh
5 6 7 8 9 10
$ echo -e '-1000 -900 -100 -100 -100 0 0 0 +100 +100 +100' | ./script.sh
-1000 -900 -100 -99 -98 0 1 2 100 101 102
$ echo -e ' 1 1\n 1\n 1 \n1 \n1 ' | ./script.sh
1 2 3 4 5 6
$ echo -e 'a 1 b 2 3 c' | ./script.sh
1 2 3
```

Comment: IIUC, OP would like to replace all non-unique numbers with a new random non-unique number. In this example the second 91 should be replaced with a new number such as 93 and not removed.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Ok, revised.

Comment: @hjkefl You should have described the input spec in your question.  Please edit now to mention it, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: @mikeserv...is there a possiblity that you could post a solution..that would be amazn...

Comment: @mikeserv Yes, I used `echo $()` for that purpose to enable tests, I admit it's quite corner-cutting and undesirable solution.  I'll take a look into other indications from you.  @hjkel Thanks, I'll soon update my answer.

Comment: Updated.  Gone to the bad with Bashism in the end.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @hjkefl You can do like `./script.sh < input.txt > output.txt`.

Comment: could you maybe hav a look at my input..with this data the thing doesnt work..ther is no putput....https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp67eiw4ns9rr07/num?dl=0

Comment: @hjkefl LOL your input is outsized!  Ok we need yet another approach for that large input, please be patient until next update.

Comment: that is great..do you think well have an update alter tod? that woul be ama

Comment: @hjkefl Updated.  You can feed your input to the new script in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need:

```
#!usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                
use strict;
use warnings;

my@list=qw(2 7 8 9 11 15 34 91 91 92 94);
my%hash;


print "Input:\n@list\n";

foreach(@list)
{
    #count occurences for each element                                                                                                                        
    $hash{$_}++;
}

foreach my$key (keys %hash)
{
    TURN: while($hash{$key}>1)
    {
    #add a number between 1 and 10 to the duplicated value if                                                                                             
    #this value does not already exist                                                                                                                    
        for(my$i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        {
            if(exists $hash{$key+$i})
            {
                next;
            }
            else
            {
                $hash{$key}--;
                $hash{$key+$i}=1;
                next TURN;
            }
        }
    }
}

my@result=sort{$a<=>$b}(keys %hash);

print "Result:\n@result\n";
```

This code counts the occurences for each element and adds a number between 1 and 10 to the value to get one that does not exist already.